# EXterna Table errorORA-29913- ORA-29400- KUP-04040

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c

i created a external table when i select from it this error show.
i work with oracle 19c

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04040: file customer.csv in EXTERNAL not found
```

------------code----------------

```
CREATE TABLE customers
(Email    VARCHAR2(255)       NOT NULL,
  Name     VARCHAR2(255)         NOT NULL,
  Phone    VARCHAR2(255)         NOT NULL,
  Address  VARCHAR2(255)         NOT NULL)

ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL(
    type oracle_loader
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY external
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    ( 
      records delimited by newline
      fields terminated by ','
      missing field values are null
      REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS) 
    LOCATION ('customer.csv'))
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

customer.csv data

salma.55@gmm.com,salma,0152275522,44al,

mariam.66@hotmail.com,mariam,011145528,552www,

ahmed.85@gmail.com,ahmed,0111552774,44eee,

Comment: Where does your `default directory` object point to? Sounds like it just isn't finding the file there.

Answer (score 1):

"DEFAULT DIRECTORY external" means you are looking in a named directory that you have called "external".

For example, if I had done:

```
create directory XYZ as '/tmp';
```

then

```
default directory XYZ
```

means I'll be searching in /tmp for my files.  So look at DBA_DIRECTORIES to see where your "EXTERNAL" directory is pointing